# How to set the Output pin for a filtDirectShow filter?

Tags: types, media, directshow

I have a DirectShow application which captures Web cam images and render on screen. For each of the webcam capture filter, I can see that there are a number of output pins and corresponding media types. Please help on how to select a particular Pin based on it's media type and **how to set this as the Output pin of the Capture Filter**.

I am able to enumerate the pins, and see their media types, but remain clueless on how to say to DirectShow that "hey, this is the pin that I want you to use as the output pin".

Answer (score 0):

Pins normally agree on media types themselves, however sometimes you can set desired media type as an owner/builder of the graph. This is the case of capture devices.

See [Configure the Video Output Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd387907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN as for how to use `IAMStreamConfig::SetFormat` for this.

Bonus reading: [DirectShow Media Types and Pin Connections](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mediatype.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you found the pin you need, you can use [`IGraphBuilder::Render`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to render just that pin:

```
IPin myOutput = ...;
hr = pGraph.Render(myOutput);
```

If you also have the renderer (and it's input pin), you can also use [`IGraphBuilder::Connect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390088%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the pins "resolve the pin type you need the output one" get the and media type for each pin IPin::EnumMediaTypes and if the media type is equal with one you needed you can make the connection between you output and input pin with using the Connect method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375620(v=vs.85).aspx
http://www.flipcode.com/archives/DirectShow_For_Media_Playback_In_Windows-Part_III_Customizing_Graphs.shtml